# Checking SFTP permissions using Jsch

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

I'm currently implementing a SFTP client using Jsch.

For this client I need to check the permissions the logged in user has on the SFTP server in order to check if user is able to perform certain operations. Unfortunately I can't seem to find any documentation or examples in which is shown how to to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of permissions do you mean? File permissions on a specific file? Group membership?

Comment: Currently I working also an client, that provides some basic functions. What excactly do you need?

Comment: Basically I need to check if the logged in user has read/write permissions on the SFTP server in order to process various files.

Answer (score 4):

This code will do what you want:

```
ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");
SftpATTRS attrs = channel.lstat(fileOnServer)
boolean userHasPermissionsToWriteFile = attrs != null && ((attrs.getPermissions() & 00200) != 0) && attrs.getUId() != 0;
```

Where

```
attrs.getUId() != 0
```

checks that user is not root

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but won't that check to see the file has owner write permission? So what if the owner is someone other than the logged in user?

Answer (score -1):

Same approach in a ready method (formatted and refactored):

```
  private boolean accessAllowed(String path) 
    throws SftpException, JSchException {

    boolean result = false;

    ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    SftpATTRS attrs = channel.lstat(path);

    result =
      attrs != null &&
      ((attrs.getPermissions() & 00200) != 0) &&
       attrs.getUId() != 0;

    return result;
  }
```